# How to use styles from Angular project inside angular library?

Tags: angular, typescript, shared-libraries, angular8

**Summary :-**
In my case I have a main project on which all the other private packages(shipped as angular libraries) will be installed.
But the problem occurs in the case of using styles from parent project in the library. I only want specific styling files from my parent project.

**Please specify possible solutions for solving this problem.** 

One of the solution is to add the styling again inside library, but that would create code duplication which specifically I want to avoid.

Comment: Just add styles to your `styles.css` file and then use the classes in the library. I don't understand what else you could be asking about?

Comment: @Reactgular the issue is that I want to add bootstrap and font awesome and some other css files in the child library. Those are currently added inside my core project's angular.json.

Comment: Those are peer dependencies. Again, this is normal and the main app has to handle peer dependencies. So what are you asking? I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another library that is purely for styles, that you import into any app that requires it. This pattern is supported by [Nx](https://nx.dev) as this is their recommendation on how to handle this scenario.

Take a look at this example repo: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/tree/master/libs/shared/styles